# Web Workers and JSON

Tags: javascript, json, html, web-worker

I am sure there is something that I am missing from this code, I just can not figure out what it is.

Here is the main page:

```
  <script>
    function wwCallback(e) {
        document.write(e.data);
    }
    function wwError(e) {
        alert(e.data)
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var worker = new Worker("sync.js");
        worker.onmessage = wwCallback;
        worker.onerror = wwError;
        worker.postMessage({
            'cmd': 'downloadUser',
            'url': 'server.php'
        });
        console.log("WW Started");
    });
</script>
```

Server.php simply echoes a JSON string and I have verified that it is both valid and working using normal ajax requests.

Here is my web workers code:

```
function getData(url) {
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

//expect json
    req.open('GET', url);
    req.send(null);
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if (req.status == 200) {
                self.postMessage(req.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
} 

self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
  var data = e.data;
  switch (data.cmd) {
    case 'downloadUser':
        getData(data.url);
   }
    self.close();
}, false);
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? What happens? What should happen?

Comment: Nothing happens. The webworker is supposed to get the data from server.php and pass it back to the main page where it is written to the DOM. Problem is that I get nothing when I run it. No error's, and no idea what is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in your WebWorker XHR call. You've opened the request, then immediately sent it before you've set up the event handler to handle the response. You just need to move the `req.send(null);` call below the code that sets up the event handler.

Try this:

```
function getData(url) {
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

//expect json
    req.open('GET', url);
    //  req.send(null);        // remove this line from here.
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if (req.status == 200) {
                self.postMessage(req.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
    req.send(null);        // make the request after your readystatechange
                           // handler is set up.
} 

self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
  var data = e.data;
  switch (data.cmd) {
    case 'downloadUser':
        getData(data.url);
   }
    self.close();
}, false);
```